# Copying a file while its being written to (in Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, cron, logrotate

I am in a year-long Twitter research project, and I collect tweets via Twitters API and Twarc.

In short, this writes a new tweet as a new line to one specified file, roughly one per second at night, and more at daytime.

I would like to copy the contents of this file on a daily basis, using cron and at the same time "emptying" the main file, so that the next day will have basically a fresh file. I do not want to touch the pipeline writing the file.

Is `mv currently_written_file.txt daily-xx-xx-xx.txt & mv empty.file currently_written_file.txt` fast and stable enough for such an enterprise? Is it guaranteed to succeed, although currently_written_file.txt could be accessed any time (and is usually 100MB or more)? I am unsure.

I wondered whether something like logrotate gurantees this, but it seems that logrotate cannot be set to **not** rotate such files ;)

Comment: you may want to start here: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/file-locking

Comment: Tread carefully with logrotate. Important: does the logger keep the file open or not?

Comment: If a program opens a file and writes to it once per second, moving the file will not stop the program from continuing to write to the new name, i.e. the old huge file. If the program re-opens and write-appends to a filename every second, then you can move the file. You need to determine whether the file is kept open or re-opened for each line.